# How to identify IE browsers Build and Sub Build Numbers?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx

Using this link we are no where able to find the build and sub build version!

For more information regarding the build and sub build and how those version being generated are in this following link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393

Can anyone please help me with this?

I want to know, browsers major version.minor version.build number.subbuild number

i.e., 6.00.2800.1106

The above can also be achieved using WMI and VBScripting! and also through C# registry and managementobjects but i term those are not the exact way to identify! Is there any way to identify these build and sub build versions???

Comment: Why did you add the javascript tag and talk about WMI? I guess your scenario is client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect their user agent, and extract the data you need from there.
Their user agent is stored in:
    navigator.userAgent

An example of a user agent is as follows:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7
```

From that string, you can tell I am running windows 6.1 (win 7), and my browser is chrome 16.0.912.77.

Comment: I specifically needed the build and subbuild number...! Example i want to differentiate between two version of same IE6.0 one with SP1 and one with SP2 and SP3 ???

Comment: Maybe navigator.vendorSub?
or navigator.productSub or navigator.product

Comment: both window.navigator.product; and window.navigator.productSub returns UNDEFINED!

Answer (score 0):

Below javascript can give the browser name and application version:

```
var txt = "Browser Name: " + navigator.appCodeName;
txt+= " and Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion;
alert(txt); // alerts the browser name and version
```

Comment: Nope; Dint work...! it doesn't give me the build and sub build number!

Comment: how did you tested and in which browser ?

Comment: I have environment setup which has different version of IE6.0 starting from IE6.0 SP1 to IE6.0 SP3, IE7.0, IE 8.0, IE9.0.

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript is available, you can use the [JQuery Browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) values. If I recall correctly the implementation is marked as deprecated, but I used in the past for a project and had no problem with it.
On the demopage is shows values that contain sub build numbers.

Part of the javascript file that I used:

```
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '7.0') {
        // do something
    }
```